# Sorting strings list by descending string length, doesn't change the list

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I want to sort a copy of an immutableList by descending string length. I have to support API below java 8.

I try this basic code, but it's still in reverse order

```
ImmutableList<String> possibleTexts = ImmutableList.of("aa", "bbbbbb");
final List<String> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(possibleTexts);
Collections.sort(mutableList, (s1, s2) -> Math.abs(s1.length() - s2.length()));
```

and yet mutableList is `"aa", "bbbbbb"` instead of `"bbbbbb","aa"`

Comment: `Math.abs()` will make everything non-negative. The result of comparison needs to be negative, `0` or positive.

Comment: Check out the Javadocs for “sort”; they describe what should be returned by the comparator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is the opposite of what you expect because `Math.abs(s1.length() - s2.length())` returns `4` for both `|2 - 6|` and `|6 - 2|`.

The documentation of [`Collections#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) also states the following:

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

To fix your issue, you can remove [`Math#abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) and swap your comparison (the length of a `String` cannot be negative, so no overflow/underflow will occur):

```
Collections.sort(mutableList, (s1, s2) -> s2.length() - s1.length());
```

However, I'd recommend using [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) with [`Comparator#comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) and [`Comparator#reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()), as it's more readable to me than your current snippet.

Comment: Correct. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Build the Comparator using `comparing` and select the length as a key and reverse the order

```
mutableList.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());
```

Comment: You should call sort on the List instead of using Collections

Answer (score 0):

```
 Collections.sort(mutableList,(s1,s2)->Integer.compare(s2.length(),s1.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The sorting itself has already been answered, but you can use a stream rather than create an explicit copy of the list.

```
List<String> sorted = possibleTexts.stream()
                          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed())
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```